# @Autowired outside @Bean got nullpointerexception

Tags: spring

My src code like below, how I can fix this?

```
@Component("shiroSecurityConfig")
public class ShiroSecurityConfig {
    @Autowired (required = true)
    private TestService testService;

    @Bean(name = "shiroFilter")
    public ShiroFilterFactoryBean shiroFilter() {
        testService.getrecords(); //this line got null pointer exception.
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your configuration context xml file otherwise in configuration context.xml file use component scanner to scan your package , so that autowiring can be done on all classes.

Comment: The question is why are you using this way? You have TestService and you can inject it in any bean whenever you need ShiroFilterFactoryBean and just call method getrecords(). Or you can add @Bean to TestService#getrecords(). I think it would be better

Answer (score 2):

Autowiring always happens after the construction of bean objects that is why you are getting your testService as null as it is not autowired yet, for more information about bean life cycle please refer

http://www.dineshonjava.com/2012/07/bean-lifecycle-and-callbacks.html.